# newly purchased and formatted (ext4) seagate external hard drive 5tb cannot store files in Lubuntu 18.10 + almost 40gb used somehow

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, external-hdd, filemanager

I recently purchased a new external Seagate 5tb drive. I am running Lubuntu 18.10 from an external Sandisk USB drive.

I tried to format the 5tb external drive using mkfs.ext4 using the terminal but once i did that, it was not appearing on the file manager sidebar. So I downloaded and used Gparted. Created a GPT partition table and formatted the whole 5tb drive to ext4.

Now the drive appears on the file manager sidebar, but when i try to drag and drop a file, from my Lubuntu usb drive to the external seagate 5tb drive, nothing happens. I tried rebooting, and when i try to move/copy the file again, I get this message:

Error opening file “/media/h/f0de3be3-77d2-4ef0-95d9-65f6b7ac5451/testfile.jpg”: Permission denied

Could someone please explain

1. how i may get the external hard drive to be useable?  Is it possibly faulty?  Could I have done something that may have damaged it by formatting it. Could it perhaps work if i tried a different variant of ubuntu like xubuntu ?
2. why gparted says that 37.76gb is in use in this new external 5tb drive, and only 4.51tb is available ?  (The drive i bought was from ebay and heavily discounted, however, there appeared to be a seal on the package and everything seems new).

thankyou

Comment: can you post the output of `df -h`? it says you don't have permissions, it happened to me that after formatting my external drive, it was owned by root with no write permissions for anyone else, e.g. your normal user. So identifying the disk and doing a `sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) -R /path/to/disk/` may solve it. About the total space , it's never the same as advertised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how i may get the external hard drive to be useable? Is it possibly faulty? Could I have done something that may have damaged it by formatting it. Could it perhaps work if i tried a different variant of ubuntu like xubuntu ?

The problem is permissions. Run `sudo chown username:username /media/h/f0de3be3-77d2-4ef0-95d9-65f6b7ac5451/` to change ownership to your user and group. This will give you write permissions on the disk. Replace `username` with you actual username.

> why gparted says that 37.76gb is in use in this new external 5tb drive, and only 4.51tb is available ? (The drive i bought was from ebay and heavily discounted, however, there appeared to be a seal on the package and everything seems new).

First, EXT4 reserves some space for root. This defaults to 5% of the available space. This is to stop users from filling a drive completely, allowing some room for root to clean up, and some space is used for a journal.

This can be modified by running `sudo tune2fs -m 0 /dev/sdx1`, where `sdx1` is the partition. You can identify the partition by running `sudo lsblk`

Second, disks use 1TB = 1000GB, while (most of) the rest of the world uses 1TiB = 1024 GiB. This means that a drive that is advertised as 5TB is actually 5000GB, or  4.88TB. Minus the 30-ish GB consumed for journal and reserved for root, this matches the 4.51 reported as free.

Comment: if i may clarify, for the chown command i looked up the syntax is username:username however i used username.username . do both these variants have the same meaning for command?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/194295/using-dot-as-delimiter-to-specify-group-in-chown - dot is basically the old, depreceated syntax. I will update my answer :)